# I want to return a list of countries for a specified region and income group

Tags: dataframe

Write a function that will return a list of countries for a specified region and income group. If the specified region and income group do not return a country, return None as the value.

Function specifications

Argument(s):

region (string)  →
the region you want to query.
income_group (string)  →
the income group you want to query.
Return:

countries (list)  →
return a list of countries that match the search criteria or None if no countries are found.

This is the function, but I haven't tried anything I just keep getting stuck

This is the expected output:

find_countries_by_region_and_income('South Asia','High income')==None
find_countries_by_region_and_income('Europe & Central Asia','Low income')==['Tajikistan']
find_countries_by_region_and_income('Sub-Saharan Africa','Upper middle income')==['Botswana','Gabon','Equatorial Guinea','Mauritius','Namibia','South Africa']

Please help

Comment: Hi there. what have you tried so far? any attempt? what was the result? Maybe you want to check [ask] and see if you can provide us with a MCVE? without that, we won't be able to help.